# Are you intended to use NativeStorage and LocalStorage at the same time?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working in the app of my company made in Ionic 3, and I see this many times:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  // store content using NativeStorage
else {
  // do the same but using LocalStorage
}
```

People also talk about IonicStorage in forums...

I want to understand why they (my company) do this because something tells me this is not the way it should be done.

I mean, is there any better way to manage both scenarios (when the platform is 'cordova' and when it's not)? Is this why IonicStorage exists?

Answer (score 0):

Native storage only works in devices while LocalStorage can use it on the browser, for example when you are debugging or testing.

Also you can check this question to see the [differences between IonicStorage and  NativeStorage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377622/difference-between-ionic-storage-and-native-storage)

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I'm aware of the differences between those two. But it still looks like a "workaround". It's even worse that one uses promises and the other one doesn't.

Maybe we should use IonicStorage? If not, I guess this is the only way to use and test storage in browser and devices.

Comment: Well, I don't know how it is being implemented in your company. If you are looking for something more specific, try editing your question. I'll be glad of help you as much as I can

Comment: They are implementing it the way I posted. I mean, they use an "if" to check the platform, and then perform the logic. It works, of course, but when you write a logic twice, you know something is wrong. That's why I was asking if there is a better way to manage both scenarios. I'm updating the question clarifying this.